# Integrating NodeJS within MyEclipse debugger doesn't show breakpoints or stop

Tags: node.js, debugging, myeclipse, javascript-debugger, nodeclipse

I installed nodejs packages within MyEclipse, and I am able to **run** nodejs applications and hit my REST API.

But when it comes to **debugging**: there is no option of adding a breakpoint when clicking on the line number on the left side of the editor, by double clicking it adds them but they don't show. Afterall it doesn't jump to MyEclipse when URL is called.

Does the integration work with MyEclipse? Or I am forced to use nodeclipse?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript debugging was added with MyEclipse 2015 CI 15. You need to Debug As ... JavaScript in Java EE Web Application. This requires Chrome to be installed. Check out the details in [this tutorial](https://www.genuitec.com/products/myeclipse/learning-center/web/myeclipse-javascript-development-and-debugging-tutorial/).

Comment: Could it be because teh project is a Javascript project and not J2EE?

Comment: As a Javascript project can't be run/debugged, I guess it would have to be included in a Web project (via the MyEclipse/JavaScript/JavaScript Resources preferences page). Is that your setup? If so, debug the including project as mentioned above.